# Convert an optimal basis from Simplex to an actual solution

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, simplex, operations-research, two-phase-simplex

I may not be understanding the Simplex algorithm very well, or even if my problem is a problem at all so I'll use an example.

Given an optimization problem:

```
LP PB:
min z = +2x1 +3x2
st. +3x1 +2x2 = 14
    +2x1 -4x2 >= 2
    +4x1 +3x2 <= 19
    x1, x2 >= 0
```

Convert to std form:

```
STD LP PB:
min z = +2x1 +3x2
st. +3x1 +2x2 = 14
    +2x1 -4x2 -x3 = 2
    +4x1 +3x2 +x4 = 19
    x1, x2, x3, x4 >= 0
```

After applying Simplex and the 2-Phase method for generating the initial basis I get the following solution:

```
x1 = 4.666...
x2 = 0
x3 = 7.333...
x4 = 0.333...
```

With the basis being `{x1, x3, x4}` obviously.

In this case, since the original problem simply "asks" to find the optimal values for `x1` and `x2`, do I just take the values of `x1` and `x2` from the solution given by simplex and that's it? Or how do you get the values for the original problem?

Comment: You added some auxiliary variables and when you report the solution you can ignore them. This has nothing to do with simplex, you would be able to do the same no matter what optimization algorithm was used.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Thank you! Makes sense. Can you add an answer so I can accept it?